# Display Label on TableView . This disappear when scrolling TableView

Tags: ios, label, tableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a TableView with the label that hidden and only appear when I click on the cell through didSelectRow.

So far so good, when I select the cell the orange label (as you can see from the image) is displayed, but there is a problem when the tableView scrolls the label orange disappears and comes back only if I change the page ...

The orange label indicates if the friend request is pending or not, and makes reference to a query exists in another page thanks to a mutable array reported with a prepareforsegue.

Can you explain why the orange label disappears?? How do I make it stay on the TableView when I select the cell?
The Label Orange is "RichiestaInAttesaLabel"
P.s. I'm using Parse.com

```
-(UITableViewCell * )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    FFCustomCellUtentiGenerali  *cell =[self.TableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FFCustomCellUtentiGenerali alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }


if (!isFiltered) {

    PFObject *object = [self.Utenti objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *str = [object objectForKey:FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME];
    cell.NomeCognome.text = str;

    cell.FFFotoProfilo.file = [object objectForKey:FF_USER_FOTOPROFILO];
    cell.FFFotoProfilo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FFNoFotoUSer"];
    [cell.FFFotoProfilo.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.FFFotoProfilo.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];
    cell.FFFotoProfilo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    [cell.FFFotoProfilo loadInBackground];

    [cell.BackgroundReputazioneBlu.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.BackgroundReputazioneBlu.layer setCornerRadius:15.0f];
    [cell.BackGroundReputazione.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.BackGroundReputazione.layer setCornerRadius:17.0f];
    [cell.TapAggiungiLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.TapAggiungiLabel.layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];
    [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel.layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];

    PFUser *user = [self.Utenti   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.TapAggiungiLabel setHidden:YES];
    [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:NO];


    if ([self isFriend:user]) {
         [cell.TapAggiungiLabel setHidden:YES];
        [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES];
    }

    else {


        [cell.TapAggiungiLabel setHidden:NO];
        [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES  ];
    }



    if ([self Is_InAttesa:user]) {
        [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:NO];
        [cell.TapAggiungiLabel setHidden:YES];

    }

    else {
        [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES];

    }

}
//end IsFiltred
else {
```

[image]

Comment: where finish if(!isFiltered) {   ?

Answer (score -1):

```
if ([self isFriend:user]) {
     [cell.TapAggiungiLabel setHidden:YES];
    [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES];
}

else {


    [cell.TapAggiungiLabel setHidden:NO];
    [cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES  ];
}
```

why "cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES" in both cases?

Comment: because self isFriend: user recognizes if they are friends or not

self Is_InAttesa: user recognizes if a request is pending or not

Comment: Why don't you set "[cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel setHidden:YES];" once in the beginning and change it to "NO" in "if ([self Is_InAttesa:user]) {..." ?

Comment: I tried to do this but when I scroll the TableView the orange label disappears

Comment: can you log the cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel.hidden in the end of the method? is it visible?

Comment: Excuse the translator got crazy ... I could not understand what you wanted to say

Comment: Can you add "NSLog(@"is visible: %d", cell.RichiestaInAttesaLabel.hidden)" in the end of the method?

Comment: 2013-11-15 13:37:29.779 UniGo![2139:60b] is visible: 1
2013-11-15 13:37:29.787 UniGo![2139:60b] is visible: 1
2013-11-15 13:37:29.794 UniGo![2139:60b] is visible: 1
2013-11-15 13:37:29.799 UniGo![2139:60b] is visible: 1
2013-11-15 13:37:29.806 UniGo![2139:60b] is visible: 1
2013-11-15 13:37:29.812 UniGo![2139:60b] is visible: 1